# Uploading my ios app to the app store says I don't have any eligibile applications for upload

Tags: ios, upload

Wy app loader keeps doing this: I filled out all the necessary information about the app, and it appears in itunes connect (manage my applications). And it says (prepare for upload) below the app in itunes connect. But when I start the app loader, it says I don't have any eligible applications for upload. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to double check, after you have completed entering all your details in iTunesConnect have you gone back into your app (in iTunesConnect) and clicked 'Ready to upload binary' at the top right.  Once you're in this state it should appear in the AppLoader list after you re-run AppLoader.  It's not obvious that you need to do this so may be the issue.

If it doesn't, is there a chance it is using the wrong Apple account?  If so try loading AppLoader and running the AppLoader setup wizard (for anyone new to mac like me:by running AppLoader and looking in the Window menu options at the top of the screen).  This will allow you to log in again so hopefully something will appear.
Hope this helps solve it.

Comment: For a company that is famous for obsessing over the user interface and user experience, this sure is a weird way to do it :)